# Fetch To-Many NSSets from each result and calculate sum

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, one-to-many

I have the following core data model:

[image: Data Model]

I am fetching entities of PbsRow depending on user selection (the user can choose timeframes which are saved in jahr (year) and monat (month)). After fetching the request, I have an NSArray with a couple of PbsRow instances. What I would like to do is to calculate the sum of ALL WarengruppeVK entities (e.g. for netto) which belong to each PbsRow entity. I have tried doing this by valueForKeyPath but this doesn't seem to work for me :-(.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand it correctly, you want all existing WarengruppeVK-s? In this case just make an `NSFetchRequest`, set the entity to `WarengruppeVK` and leave the predicate `nil`.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

In this case, you can go through your fetched data with a for, and each entity should have an `NSSet` property called `warengruppeVK` containing all it's WarengruppeVKs.

Comment: No, not all of them. I just want the WarengruppeVKs which belong to PbsRows where e.g. "jahr" is 2012. I'm already fetching the PbsRows correctly, now I need the corresponding sets of WarengruppeVks.

Comment: I dont know if this is the best way, I have about 3000-4000 objects in my array and each object has a NSSet of WarengruppeVKs... But i will try it.

Comment: Well at some point you will need a for cycle, can't do this without. If you want a total value (not a sum for each PbsRows), you could make a fetch request for all WarengruppVKs, where the RbsRows property meets that time related condition. The entity would be WarengruppeVK and the predicate's format would look something like @"pbsrow.year == 2013". This would be faster, since you would need a single for to go through the results.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking about... Fortunately i only need the total sum of all WarengruppeVKs.

Comment: What about NSExpression? Shouldn't it be possible to achieve that by using NSExpression? Or is this something different?

Answer (score 0):

You should feel free to treat managed object subclasses as subclasses under your control.  Teach them new tricks, like answering the year.

```
// PbsRow.h
- (NSInteger)year;

// PbsRow.m
- (NSInteger)year {
   // return some function of self.jahr that you can write
}
```

Then ...

```
NSInteger warrenGroupeCount = 0;
for (PbsRow *pbsRow in fetchResults) {
    if ([pbsRow year] == 2012)
        warrenGroupeCount += pbsRow.warengruppeVK.count;
}
```

Comment: I cant believe there is no other way to do this. Is there nothing similar to valueForKeyPath?

Answer (score 0):

Step one: fetch your WarengruppeVK with a fetch request including this predicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pbsrow IN %@", pbsRowArray];
```

Step two: use the value for key path mechanism.

```
[warengruppeVKArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.netto"];
```